# Is TFDTable.AppendRecord Injection-Safe

Tags: sql, delphi, dataset, sql-injection, firedac

There is a method `procedure AppendRecord(const Values: array of const);` that is present in `TDataSet`, `TFDTable` etc. If we follow in depth of `TDataset` source (I do not have FireDac Source). The data is set by `SetFields(Values);` and `Fields[I].AssignValue(Values[I])` methods.
I wonder if it is safe in terms of SQL-injections to pass something like this: `MyFireDacDS.AppendRecord([..., Edit1.Text, ...])`?

Comment: iiuc everything which uses parametrized SQL statements instead of constructing the SQL INSERT from strings is safe. So I would check if the code eventually uses plain string operations to set the field values.

Comment: `AppendRecord` does not accept SQL as any of the values, and checks each value against the field it's to be assigned to, so there is zero risk of SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AppendRecord` does not use any of the `Values` as executable SQL, and therefore cannot be vulnerable to SQL injection any more than a parameterized query.

SQL injection only applies to dynamically constructed SQL using unvalidated input, and as AppendRecord does not use such SQL, it's not subject to the risk of SQL injection.

(You could, of course, test this yourself by trying to pass SQL as one of the `Value` items and seeing what happens.)

Comment: Nicely put.  I wish more answers on Sql_injection included a phrase like "using unvalidated input", +1.

Comment: Thank you, Ken, Hope the `AppendRecord` method used by `TFDTable` is really the same as that of `TDataSet`